# Linker complains about missing vtkCommon when using PCL

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew, vtk, point-cloud-library

I try to get a pcl setup running on macOS 10.13.5 unsing homebrew.

I tried to install pcl with both techniques `brew install pcl` and `brew install --build-from-source pcl`

As dependencie `vtk` (8.1.1) is installed automatically and I can see that those libaries are installed in `/usr/local`.

But in the linking stage I get the following error:

> ld: library not found for -lvtkCommon
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

If I check the list of installed libraries I can verify that there is not `vtkCommon` only a `vtkCommonCore`

In CMake I use the following lines to include PCL, the `vtkCommon` appears in the `${PCL_LIBRARIES}` variable.

```
find_package(PCL REQUIRED COMPONENTS filters surface kdtree features segmentation)
list(APPEND include_directories ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
list(APPEND used_libraries  ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how it can be solved?

Comment: Looks like you have a file `PCLConfig.cmake`, used in `find_package(PCL)` request, incompatible with your PCL installation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks. That was exatcly the problem. There were two `PCLConfig.cmake` on this system. Uninstalling PCL and removing the remaining `PCLConfig.cmake` and reinstalling pcl solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Tsyvarev the problem was that an a not match `PCLConfig.cmake` was existed alongside to the correct one, deleting that incorrect on solved the problem.